# how to return on product's detail page in NopCommerce 3.20

Tags: nopcommerce

I want to create plugin which shows Category-vice MostViewed Products.
So i need to know how to return on Product's detail page from my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should create in your plugin's controller method like Product() method in Nop.Web\Controllers\CatalogController.cs which method, that will return your new views or default views from Nop.Web.